# How to exit android app?

Tags: android, haxe, openfl

In OpenFL, I need to exit my Android app. Is there a way to do so using openFL APIs?

I've found an old thread here http://www.openfl.org/archive/community/general-discussion/exit-an-app/

but it seems `Lib.exit();` is no more there? As I didn't find exit method in `Lib`

Any idea?

Comment: You shouldn't need this. Users on Android expect the back button to take them out of an app (and for the task switcher to be able to bring them back into the app). There are similar expectations on iOS.

Comment: I know, but there is an exit button shown in case user failed to activate his app, its a screen that shows something like "Your subscription has expired, Renew, No thanks" where No thanks would exit the app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preferred method now (as of OpenFL 3) is:

```
openfl.system.System.exit(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure since my last openfl project was a few versions ago, but I'd imagine that `Lib.exit()` still exists.

The method doesn't exist for flash target, so if you're using something like flashdevelop which looks at the flash documentation for auto competing, the method won't show, but if you put the method inside of a `#if android` it should work.

Comment: Thank you! it worked for me, I am using openFL 1.2.2, I thought its not working as I didn't see it in auto complete list at FlashDevelop